# There is already an object named 'IX_MY_INDEX_NAME' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Once a week (or so), I receive the following error message within my multi-threaded application:

> There is already an object named 'IX_MY_INDEX_NAME' in the database.
>   Could not create constraint.

The SP in question creates a temp table as follows:

```
--removed for brevity
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    [IndexId] INT UNIQUE IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [WhateverId] INT NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] INT NULL,
    [VendorId] INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT IX_MY_INDEX_NAME UNIQUE (
        WhateverId,
        CustomerId,
        VendorId
    )
)
--removed for brevity
```

What causes this to happen? Isn't the above statement atomic? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constraints need to be uniquely named in a database; in your above example, if two threads execute at roughly the same time, there's a possibility that a temporary table with that constraint will exist while the second one is being created.

To do what you want to do, create a UNIQUE index after the table is created; index names don't have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

2 thoughts come to mind. 
1) It depends on how you generate your constraint name: IX_MY_INDEX_NAME. The error is stating that the index named has already been used (possibly for another table). 
2) You mentioned it is a multi-threaded application, is it possible two threads are attempting to execute the same create statement. To rule this out, you can alter your table creation to only create if it doesn't exist. e.g. Oracle/Mysql -> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS